# how can show child out of stock of configurable product in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I am currently using Magento 2.2.3 and I am having some inventory issues with Configurable Products. I am trying to show Out of Stock Simple Products in the Dropdown but let the Customer know it is out of stock when selected.
When I `getAttributesData` of product via  `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeData.php`  but it don't have product is out of stock.

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something very similar and I am using the answer from this question as a start point but it does what you need.

[Magento 2.2 How to show out of stock in configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product)

Hope it helps you with your query.

Comment: All credit to "Ravindrasinh Zala"