# ConfigurableProduct: How to get the configurable products out of stock?

Tags: magento2, module, configurable-product, overrides

I want to show all the attributes from my configurable product on my select. I followed this tutorial: [Magento 2.2 How to show out of stock in configurable product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product), with some changes and fixes.

So, I can't override the configurable.phtml file, because the Magento Interceptors can't load the *decorateArray* method.

What I want exactly is for the products to be displayed in this format, like image:
[image: example]

But I don't know where the method to override this is located and how to get all product attributes.