# Product option not shown when out of stock?

Tags: magento2, stock

In my **Magento 2.2.3** shop the option images and dropdowns are not shown if the product is out of stock. I want them anyway but just the add to cart button should not be shown. The images are shown on the category page, which is correct.

Is there some setting for that by any chance?

Thanks

Comment: you are using configurable products?

Comment: Yes, thats configurable products.

Comment: try this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product