# Display Out of Stock Simple Products swatches in configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.3, out-of-stock

**Configurable product** should display all **simple products**, also the simple products which are out of stock.

For example an item has the sizes S, M, L, XL. And M is out of stock.

At this moment it only shows S L XL.

I need Magento to show also the size M (with an "out of stock" css class added to it).

How can I fix this for Magento 2.3(!) ?

Comment: Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options Set Display "Out of Stock Products" to YES

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: did you reindex / recache the website after enabling it

Comment: Yes, and it is a known issue (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15047).

So I'm curious how it can work for you? Do you maybe have a preview url, where you got it working? Because I think you don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried this (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216373/magento-2-2-how-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product) solution?

Comment: @Bernd have to get any solution related to this ?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The above one is a known issue for Magento and can be solved partially by installing the below extension.

https://github.com/interjar/configurable-child-visibility

Reference for the Issue can be found at [Magento Issue 10454](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10454)

Answer (score 0):

To make visible swatshes that related to out of stock products try to make such changes

1. Create your own module
2. Create **etc/di.xml** file

add there code

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data">
    <plugin name="VendorName_ModuleName_Plugin_Magento_ConfigurableProduct_Helper_Data"
            type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

3. Create Plugin Class VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data

/

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
* Plugin for making visible swatches that related to  out of stock products
* depend on the setting admin->Stores->configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options->Out of Stock Products
*/
class Data
{
    const SHOW_OUT_OF_STOCK_CONFIG_PATH = "cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock";
    protected ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    /** 
    *@param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    */    
    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param $currentProduct
     * @param $allowedProducts
     * @return array
     */
public function aroundGetOptions(
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Data $subject,
    \Closure                                 $proceed,
                                             $currentProduct,
                                             $allowedProducts

) {
    $result = $proceed($currentProduct, $allowedProducts);

    $show_out_of_stock = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::SHOW_OUT_OF_STOCK_CONFIG_PATH,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $options = [];
    $allowAttributes = $subject->getAllowAttributes($currentProduct);

    foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        foreach ($allowAttributes as $attribute) {
            $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
            $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
            $attributeValue = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
            if ($show_out_of_stock || $product->isSalable()) {
                $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
            }
            $options['index'][$productId][$productAttributeId] = $attributeValue;
        }
    }

    return $options;
  }
}
```